# How to bins values and plot

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I have a dataset with two columns, the first column is duration (length of time (e.g. 5 min) and the second column is firing rates. Is it possible to plot this in such a way that firing rates are binned according to corresponding duration (e.g. 5, 10, 15 min) and then plot bars with firing rate on the y axis and time on the x?

Comment: Yes, it's called a histogram. Check out https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html for more details.

Comment: No, I dont want to plot frequency on the y axis, I want it to be firing rate. Read the question more closely before you downvote....

Comment: Are you looking for a [bar plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) with firing rates binned by duration (duration bin on horizontal axis) and firing rate on vertical axis?  Are your duration values limited to fixed bins (5, 10, 15) or do you need to group them via some preprocessing?  e.g.  (2.4, 4.1, 5.2) --> 5   (please [edit] your question to clarify so your clarification isn't buried in comments)

Comment: Yes, exactly. They do need preprocessing to be grouped

Comment: Is the vertical axis the mean (average) firing rate? The median?

Comment: Yes, its the average

Comment: Thanks! Please [edit] the question to include these clarifications so they aren't buried in comments.  Can you post a good [MCV-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your attempted code so far? Also include your version (e.g. release 2017b).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this can be accomplished without the `for` loop.  Solution below uses the `discretize` function to accomplish the grouping. Other approaches possible.

```
% MATLAB R2017a
% Sample data
D = 20*rand(25,1);
FR = 550*rand(25,1);
D_bins = (0:5:20)';

ind = discretize(D,D_bins);                % groups data
FR_mean = zeros(length(D_bins),1);
for k = 1:length(D_bins)
    FR_mean(k) = mean(FR(ind==k));
end

bar(D_bins,FR_mean)                        % bar plot


% Cosmetics
xlabel('Duration (min)')
ylabel('Mean Firing Rate (unit)')
```

I'm positive there's a more efficient way to get the means for each group, possibly using `arrayfun` or some other nifty functions, but will hold off until OP provides more details.